# Asterisk outbound calls per extension

Tags: asterisk

I have an asterisk server where i have a group of extensions that can make an outbound call. These extensions will never receive a call and are kinda one time use. Meaning a user will use it and then it will be randomly assigned to another user. Users can range from 1 to X rather than creating say 100 extensions could I just reuse the same Extension for every user? Are there limitations to this opposed to giving each user a dedicated extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asterisk not care what you do with extensions. How you expect it do that?

You even can have few billions extensions on server, only few loaded in memory and working.

Only limitation is number of extensions you put in your config file. If you need number of different extensions, user asterisk realtime/extensions in mysql.

You are responsible for tracking which extensions used by which user at current time, asterisk will not do that becuase of no info availible at pbx level.

Comment: Not sure if this answers my question or not. Are you saying the number of calls is based on what asterisk can handle or based on the extension? Is there a technical problem with 20 users using  one extension doing ~20 simultaneous calls to different endpoints? Or should I have twenty extensions one call per extension?

Comment: There is no difference. You can have 1 millions extensions(different, 6 digits) and it will work fine if same moment not all registered. If you use same credentials same time should be no problem, but will be logical problem and it have no sense. Dimensioning depend of 1) how many extensions is registered NOW(if you not use registration, that is 0), 2) how much calls you have now(on modern boxes that is usually supported 100-600 depend of codec).

Comment: 20 different extensions and 20 users share same credential WILL produce SAME load. So for monitoring purpose better give each one different credential.